# Type 'Promise<ConnectionPool> & void' is missing the following properties from type 'ConnectionPool'

Tags: typescript, node-mssql

I'm trying to make a connection and returning the pool using the mssql package.

```js
const sqlConfig = {
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_CATALOG,
    server: process.env.SERVER_HOST
}

export async function connect(){
    try{
        const pool = await sql.connect(sqlConfig)
        return pool
    }catch(err){
        throw err
    }
}
```

However when returning the pool, I get the following lint error:
`Type 'Promise<ConnectionPool> & void' is missing the following properties from type 'ConnectionPool': connected, connecting, healthy, driver, and 26 more.`

How should I rewrite the code to return the pool as a ConnectionPool rather than a Promise<ConnectionPool> & void?

For reference, here's the full code:

```js
import sql, { ConnectionPool } from "mssql"
require('dotenv').config()

const sqlConfig = {
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_CATALOG,
    server: process.env.SERVER_HOST
}

export async function connect():Promise<ConnectionPool>{
    try{
        const pool = await sql.connect(sqlConfig)
        return pool
    }catch(err){
        throw err
    }
}
```

I tried casting the variable to ConnectionPool and explicitly writing the expected return value, like this:

```js
export async function connect():Promise<ConnectionPool>{
    try{
        const pool = await sql.connect(sqlConfig)
        return pool as ConnectionPool
    }catch(err){
        throw err
    }
}
```

I have also tried adding overloads to the @types/mssql package taken from https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/1063 despite being an older post.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. Can you create a minimal reproduceable example project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are awaiting a promise is treating return value as a ConnectionPool object and not the promise.

if you want connect to return the connection pool change your return type to ConnectionPool, if you still want it to return a promise remove the await as seen below and call your connect function with await

```
export async function connect():Promise<ConnectionPool>{
        return sql.connect(sqlConfig);
    }catch(err){
        throw err
    }
}
```

then call it with `await connect()` or

```
connect().then( (pool ) => {
   // Do something with pool here
}
```

I would suggest the .then instead of await

Comment: Is it because .then() is a better practice or is it personal preference?

Comment: personal preference for me, I avoid using async and away and use just promises.